# What are the strong use cases for Gradle xcode plugin (openbakery) over using xcodebuild?

Tags: objective-c, jenkins, xcode7, gradle-plugin, ios9.3

Ours is sn enterprise iOS project but simple one in which developers use Xcode to build the project. Are there sufficient reasons for me to convince them to use [Gradle Xcode plugin (Openbakery)](https://openbakery.org/gradle.html) over Xcodebuild? One of the points I found in a forum is when Jenkins is a non-Mac machine, this helps, but our Jenkins server seems to be having Xcode already. But I really like the Gradle plugin and what it provides, but what are the strong points to convince its usage over Xcodebuild?

Thanks,
Padmanabhan

Answer (score 2):

We are using it for a number of reasons:

1. Technology consistency between our iOS and Android build scripts
2. Easily manage signing the same app with different bundle IDs and provisioning profiles. Some of our apps are distributed signed for both Enterprise and via the App Store so they can't share bundle IDs.
3. Preference for embedding build logic in Gradle scripts as opposed to shell scripts.
4. We use HockeyApp for distributing test builds, there is good support for that in the Gradle plugin.

Comment: Hi @DaveTrux, this plugin does not seem to support multiple provisioning profile configurations? How does your team manage to use multiple profiles and still do all build & package steps in one gradle file using the Openbakery Xcode plugin for gradle (assuming that is what you use)?

Comment: It's not a feature of the plugin, it's a Gradle feature. Something like this gist: https://gist.github.com/davetrux/ed648e69fb964c90d8ff71a63118a13f